# What defines all non-relative links?

Tags: html, regex, hyperlink

I'm looking for a way do differ between relative and non-relative links on an html page.

What defines all non-relative links? I'm looking for some sort of regular expression.

for example, do all non-relative links contain `://` and relative links never display it?

Comment: Won't relative links not have `/` as the first character

Comment: @Preet, no.  [Protocol-relative links](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2009/10/15/did-you-know-about-protocol-relative-hyperlinks.aspx) start with /.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute across the internet start with `http://` or `https://` (or whatever other scheme they may be using. I guess you could "contains" `://` as you said).

Hrefs starting with a slash (`/`) are both absolute from and relative to the web-server path

Paths starting with letters/numbers/symbols or `../` are relative to the page's file path, with `../` meaning "next folder up".

Comment: no.  If it starts with //, it's a [protocol-relative URL](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2009/10/15/did-you-know-about-protocol-relative-hyperlinks.aspx) that may be to a different web server.

Comment: Good call, Mike. You are correct. I'm used to calling it protocol, because it typically is a protocol, but as you noted it is identified as "scheme". I'll be reading that wiki article.